# How to handle view throwing manual exception in django in unit-testing?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-unittest

I have made a django application and am writing tests for it.
In one of my views I'm manually throwing an exception:

`raise Http404('Not authorised')`

While writing test for that using django's built-in test framework(based on unittest).

TL;DR: Is there way to write test such that it makes sure that the view is indeed returning `Http404`. ( `assertEqual(response.status_code, 404` doesn't work)

Comment: Did you try using [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)? Also could you show your test code?

Comment: Will check out assertRaises! thanks @shiplu.mokadd.im

Comment: "doesn't work" is not clear enough. Please paste the full traceback

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
resp = self.client.get(url)
self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 404)
```

Run your tests via:

```
python manage.py test
```

If it does not, recheck your code and supply an error message.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work. `assertEqual` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If self.assertEqual doesn't work you could try it with a with tag as shown here
[assertRaises(exception, callable, *args, **kwds)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)

```
with self.assertRaises(Http404):
    // your logic here
```

For example. I have a function that will return an order or raise a HTTP 404 response

```
from django.http import Http404

def test_get_order_with_method_404(self):
    client = MyPaymentClient("super_secret_key")
    with self.assertRaises(Http404):
        client.get_order_with_method("payment_id", "payment_method")
```

You could also do it with get_object_or_404

Example:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

with self.assertRaises(Http404):
    get_object_or_404(MyModel, some_argument="MyCriteria")
```

Well i guess you get the point. Hope this helps you out!